# Automatically move the screen to view the selection with an Excel add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to make a function to select a range in a workbook and visualise that range on the screen. My test shows that `select()` does select a range, whereas it does not always adapt automatically the screen to show the selection.

For example, I try to select and show `Z10:Z10` under `Excel for Windows` by the following code. But after the selection, the screen does not move:

```
Office.initialize = function(reason) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        app.initialize();
        $('#testSelect').click(function() { select("Z10:Z10", "Sheet1") });
    });
};

function select (rangeAddress, sheetName) {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).getRange(rangeAddress);
        range.select();
        return ctx.sync(); 
    });
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option here in the callback after your code completes is to bind to the range and then [navigate](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.gotobyidasync) to it:

```
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(Office.BindingType.Matrix, {id: "myBinding"}, function(asyncResult){
    Office.context.goToByIdAsync("myBinding", Office.GoToType.Binding, function(asyncResult){});
});
```

-Michael Saunders, PM for Office add-ins

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug (or regression) in the APIs. The team is looking into it right now. In terms of a workaround, what Michael Saunders suggested above is probably your best short-term bet.

**Update**: This is indeed a bug (or regression) in the Excel desktop client. We have fixed it today, so for Office 365 / Click-to-Run users, it should be available with the next update (i.e., within a couple months).

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, Developer on Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Confirmed that it's a regression.  See update to answer.